# execute R via sp_execute_external_script throws Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

Tags: r, sql-server-2017

I am trying to run this simple proof of concept:

```
DECLARE @p1 INT;
DECLARE @p2 INT;

    SET @p1 = 1;
    SET @p2 = 2;

    execute sp_execute_external_script
        @language=N'R',
        @script=N'inp_dat <- InputDataSet
                  inp_dat$sum <- inp_dat$p1 + inp_dat$p2
                  new_dat <- inp_dat',
        @input_data_1 = N'SELECT @p1 AS p1, @p2 AS p2',
        @output_data_1 = N'newdat';
```

Here 2 parameters are passed as a table to R which then creates a computed column and return the R data frame as table. I am currently getting:

```
Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.
```

Any ideas?

PS:

This works in the sense that I get the sum back:

```
DECLARE @p1 int;
DECLARE @p2 int;

SET @p1 = 2;
SET @p2 = 3;

DECLARE @inquery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @inquery = N'SELECT ' + CAST(@p1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N' AS p1, ' + CAST(@p2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N' AS p2;'

DECLARE @sum FLOAT; 

EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'R',
  @script=N'
            sum <- InputDataSet[1,1] + InputDataSet[1,2]
          ',
  @input_data_1 = @inquery, 
  @params = N'@sum FLOAT OUTPUT',
  @sum = @sum OUTPUT 
  ;

  SELECT @sum AS SUM
GO
```

PPS:

Getting there - only problem - column names of dataframe not returned:

```
DECLARE @p1 int;
DECLARE @p2 int;

SET @p1 = 2;
SET @p2 = 3;

DECLARE @inquery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @inquery = N'SELECT ' + CAST(@p1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N' AS p1, ' + CAST(@p2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N' AS p2;'

DECLARE @sum FLOAT; 

EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'R',
  @script=N'
            sum <- InputDataSet[1,1] + InputDataSet[1,2]
            InputDataSet$sum <- InputDataSet$p1 + InputDataSet$p2
            OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet
          ',
  @input_data_1 = @inquery, 
  @params = N'@sum FLOAT OUTPUT',
  @sum = @sum OUTPUT 
  ;

  SELECT @sum AS SUM
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [this excellent series](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/sql-server-r-services-basics/), which lead me to this solution:

```
DECLARE @p1 int;
DECLARE @p2 int;

SET @p1 = 2;
SET @p2 = 3;

DECLARE @inquery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @inquery = N'SELECT ' + CAST(@p1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N' AS p1, ' + CAST(@p2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N' AS p2;'

DECLARE @sum FLOAT; 

EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language =N'R',
  @script=N'
            InputDataSet$sum <- InputDataSet$p1 + InputDataSet$p2
            OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet
          ',
  @input_data_1 = @inquery 
  WITH RESULT SETS(( p1 INT,p2 INT,[sum] INT))
;
```

Comment: The doc itself for ´sp_execute_external_script´ is quite rich https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017